# User's LastAccessDate Is No Longer Updating as of 6/1/2010

Tags: support, data-dump

I was just playing around with the [ODATA stream for Stackoverflow](https://odata.sqlazurelabs.com/OData.svc/v0.1/rp1uiewita/StackOverflow) in LINQPad and it would appear that the User.LastActivityDate field is no longer being updated.

Looking through the data it would seem that as of 6/1/2010 the field value has not changed for any users. If we do a search for any LastAccessDate values greater than or equal to 6/2/2010 we can confirm:

```
from u in Users
where u.LastAccessDate >= new DateTime(2010, 6, 2)
select new
{
    u.Id,
    u.DisplayName,
    u.LastAccessDate
}

Result: IOrderedQueryable<> (0 items)
```

On a related note, it would seem that the last Fanatic badge was awarded on 5/24/2010. This may just be a coincidence, but I suspect that LastAccessDate correlates to the calculations used to award this badge (and possibly others).

```
from b in Badges
where b.Name == "Fanatic" && b.Date >= new DateTime(2010, 6, 2)
select new
{
    b.Date,
    b.Id,
    b.Name,
    b.UserId
}

Result: IOrderedQueryable<> (0 items)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design, the data on [odata.stackoverflow.com](http://odata.stackexchange.com/) is only updated once a month at the moment, when the data dump is released.

Some time in future we will look at refreshing weekly or even bi-weekly.